# Can you change the format of comments around XML in Visual Studio?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, formatting, comments

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio to format XML comments so that each line gets commented individually?

Here is an example of what I would like it to do (which would be more consistent with other members of my team using a different IDE):

```
    <!-- <add key="firstName" value="john" /> -->
    <!-- <add key="lastName" value="smith" /> -->
    <!-- <add key="emailAddress" value="john@smith.com" /> -->
```

But this is the way it currently formats XML comments:

```
    <!-- <add key="firstName" value="john" />
    <add key="lastName" value="smith" />
    <add key="emailAddress" value="john@smith.com" /> -->
```